# Markdown syntax with pyparsing, getting spaces correct

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm writing a small conversion program that takes a reduced Markdown syntax to html (as a learning exercise) but I'm having trouble getting the spacing correct:

```
from pyparsing import *

strong  = QuotedString("**")
text    = Word(printables)
tokens  = strong | text
grammar = OneOrMore(tokens)

strong.setParseAction(lambda x:"<strong>%s</strong>"%x[0])

A = "The **cat** in the **hat**."
print ' '.join(grammar.parseString(A))
```

What I get:

```
The <strong>cat</strong> in the <strong>hat</strong> .
```

What I would like:

```
The <strong>cat</strong> in the <strong>hat</strong>.
```

Yes this can be done *without* pyparsing and other utilities exist to do the exact same thing (e.g. pandoc) but I would like to know how to do this using pyparsing.

Comment: What is the difference, only last space before the `.`?

Comment: @Birei Yes, I don't see a clean way to solve the problem without a ton of ugly hacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very skilled with  [pyparsing](/questions/tagged/pyparsing) but I would try to use `transformString()` instead of `parseString()`, and `leaveWhitespace()` for the tokens matched, like:

```
from pyparsing import *

strong  = QuotedString("**").leaveWhitespace()
text    = Word(printables).leaveWhitespace()
tokens  = strong | text
grammar = OneOrMore(tokens)

strong.setParseAction(lambda x:"<strong>%s</strong>"%x[0])

A = "The **cat** in the **hat**."
print grammar.transformString(A)
```

It yields:

```
The <strong>cat</strong> in the <strong>hat</strong>.
```

---

**UPDATE**: Improved version pointed out by [Paul McGuire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165216/paul-mcguire) (see *comments*):

```
from pyparsing import *

strong  = QuotedString("**")

strong.setParseAction(lambda x:"<strong>%s</strong>"%x[0])

A = "The **cat** in the **hat**."
print strong.transformString(A)
```

Comment: `transformString` is very likely the right way to go. Note that `text`, `tokens`, and `grammar` are unnecessary - just do `strong.transformString(A)`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: True. I've updated my answer with your suggestion.